# FFMPEG: Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter - Error reinitializing filters

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Trying to encode a mp4 file into HLS[.m3u8] using NVIDIA Cuda Using this command:

What i'm trying to do is to convert a 1080p video file into 4 renditions resolutions: `1080p` `720p` `480p` `360p` Bellow is the `720p` example.

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mp4 -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -crf 20 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 2500k -maxrate 2675k -bufsize 3750k -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_filename output/720p_%03d.ts output/720p.m3u8
```

But this is the error i get when i run the command

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I think my issue is somewhere in the `-vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease` command but not sure with what i can replace it since i need the scale function.

Also this is the output of `ffmpeg -version`

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
configuration: --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-cuda-llvm --pkgconfigdir=/content/workspace/lib/pkgconfig --prefix=/content/workspace --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-I/content/workspace/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/content/workspace/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64' --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-shared --disable-ffplay --disable-doc --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-pthreads --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libvidstab --enable-libaom --enable-libsrt
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Answer (score 3):

Answearing my own question... i replaced `-vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease` with `-vf scale_cuda=1280:720:1:4`

Comment: *-vf scale_npp=1280:720*
if ffmpeg says no scale_cuda filter.
*ffmpeg -filters | grep scale" to check